# Is there a way to move a Bookmark line number in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using the Bookmarks feature in Visual Studio Professional 2013.

Currently Bookmarks usefully change 'Line Number' automatically if I add/delete lines of code above the Bookmark, so that the Bookmark stays with the intended line of code.

However, I've noticed recently that some Bookmarks have moved from the intended line (Line Number still the same but lines of code added/removed above). This is possibly due to updating files in Source Control Explorer and introducing other peoples changes.

Is there a way to move the Bookmark (change Line Number only) without deleting it and re-adding it?

Comment: The bookmark is set to the line number, not to the code. If you modify the code, the bookmark is retained at the line number, and does not move with the code.

Comment: In Visual Studio Professional 2013 the bookmark actually changes line number if you insert code before the bookmark. Which version of Visual Studio are you using @RobertoDeLaParra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the msdn states the bookmarks are set to a line number

> "The bookmark is set to the line number, not to the code.If you modify
>   the code, the bookmark is retained at the line number, and does not
>   move with the code"

(see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wffxsy0.aspx))

If you use Visual Studio to insert or delete line it adjusts the line number for all subsequent bookmarks but that is purely a feature of the editor.

If you update your solution containing bookmarks from SCCS for example the booksmarks stay at exactly the same line number and do not move if the update adds or removes lines.

The bookmarks are stored within binary files with a propritary structure so its difficult to manipulate.

There *could* be an extension that manages the bookmarks the way you need it.

**Alternative proposal:**

Maybe the Task List (see [MSDN about Task List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)) could help you. It lists all comments containing user defineable keywords (TODO or HACK by default) and comments move with the code even if you are updating from SCCS.

Instead of adding a bookmark just add a comment in the form `// TODO: (your description)`, open the 'Tasks'-window and select 'Comments' from the combobox to see a list of all comments containing one of the defined keywords.

Comment: That explains what is going on, many thanks. I need to be able to jump around to important parts of the code, but in a way that doesn't interfere with the actual code itself. It seems i'll need to set my bookmarks on a temporary basis (since they'll go adrift eventually).

Comment: The Task List would be nice if I could remove/change TODO as the default token word, however there are already over 200 TODOs in the codebase, the Task List is therefore overcrowded with them (could do with a filter as well!). The best thing here seems to set your own Task List token and then set it to a high priority, so that is jumps to the top of the list. Could be useful for tracking my own TODOs.

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio 2015 changed this. I cannot try this at the moment but as far as i remember it is possible to remove default keywords in VS 2015.